# The `mngo` option must be a mnnection string

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, keystonejs

I'm getting an error when I try to npm start a project.

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more information if you want some help, for example: code samples, data samples, context information.

Comment: Please don't deface your question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [Keystone.js](http://keystonejs.com/). In that case, the error message is pretty self-explanatory. Either you should provide a valid mongodb connection string in the mongo property set in keystone.js or remove it completely to work with the defaults.